# Removing number 11&12 in a top 10 R

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a top ten in R. However, the last place got 4 variables with the same number. using:

```
top.ten <- top.ten2[ top.ten2$freq >= top.ten2$freq[order(top.ten2$freq, decreasing=TRUE)][10] , ]

A 10
B 9
C 9
D 8
E 7
F 6
G 6
H 6
I 6
J 6
K 5 
L 5

M 5
N 5
```

I want to get rid of the last 2. Can somebody help me?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. The top 10 rows cuts off at `J` when I run your code, and neatly finishes after the group of `6`s.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `head(top.ten,10)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, didn't expect it to be that easy. Just getting started with R though ;)

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach would be using seq.  It will also allows to get the observations from user selected starting point to end point

```
top.ten2$freq >= top.ten2$freq[order(top.ten2$freq, decreasing=TRUE)][seq_len(10)]
```

Suppose we want from 5:10

```
top.ten2$freq >= top.ten2$freq[order(top.ten2$freq, decreasing=TRUE)][seq(5, 10)]
```